# stylesheet does not apply to html files

Tags: html, css

I've run my css through a validator (nothing is wrong)

My header looks as following (with irrelevant pieces removed)

```html
<head>
     <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lato:wght@400&display=swap" rel="Stylesheet">
     <title>Projekter</title>
     <link rel="Stylesheet" href="Stylesheet.css">
</head>
```

and my stylesheet is named Stylesheet.css in the following folder hierachy

[image: What could possibly be wrong here?]
What could possibly be wrong here?

Please do tell me if I'm missing giving some relevant information.

Comment: is the css file in the same directory?

Comment: Try this: `<link rel="Stylesheet" href="./Stylesheet.css">` Since it is in the same folder hierarchy then you must specify it.

Comment: The file is in the parent directory, so the href should be ../Stylesheet.css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The stylesheet call path is invalid.

The index.html file is in the HTML folder and Stylesheet.css is outside the HTML folder.

Please correct it as follows.

```html
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="../Stylesheet.css">
```

Chrome DevTools makes it easier to determine the cause.